Modelling a spiral drill?
How would you go modelling a spiral drill similar to the image shown?

Where the spacing between each spiral is equidistant and the angle of the outer edge is nice and straight, and the end tip isn't a mess?
Thanks in advance.

Try a lattice deform on a regular screw. I don’t use them much myself, but it might do the trick if you can sinch down one end without making the whole thing shorter.
